# Como obtener el valor de una columna y guardarlo en un array javascript

Tags: javascript, array, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla la cual en su primera columna tiene un checkbox y por medio de un script capturo todos los datos de dicha fila seleccionada, necesito tocar solo el dato de la segunda columna "numero" y guardar en un array dicho dato, de cada fila seleccionada:

```
<table class="table" id="tableImport">
        <thead>
            <tr>
           <th>Seleccion</th>
           <th>Numero</th>
           <th>Cliente</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   1
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente1
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   2
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente2
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   3
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente3
               </td>      
           </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Este es el script con el cual obtengo los datos de las filas seleccionadas:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
                var table = $('#tableImport').DataTable();
            $("#validateCustomers").click(function() {
            table.$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                        $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){
                          console.log($(this).text());
                        });
                        });
                        })
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener todos los números de la segunda columna yo lo haría de forma que le asignaría una clase `number` a la columna `td` que quiero seleccionar:

```
...
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
</td>

<td class="number">
  1
</td>
...
```

y podrías obtener el array de números de dos formas, utilizando jQuery, quedando así:

```js
const finalArray = [];

$('#tableImport .number').each(function (index,i) {
  finalArray.push(Number(i.innerText));
});

console.log(finalArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tableImport">
        <thead>
            <tr>
           <th>Seleccion</th>
           <th>Numero</th>
           <th>Cliente</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td class="number">
                   1
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente1
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td class="number">
                   2
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente2
               </td>      
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
               </td>
               <td class="number">
                   3
               </td>
               <td>
                   Cliente3
               </td>      
           </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

o sin utilizar jQuery y recurriendo a javaScript nativo tal que:

```
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('#tableImport .number')].map(i => Number(i.innerText)))
```